# Earthlink Cable Connection Problem?

Tags: internet

Okay I just got earthlink internet cable and I installed the total access software but the software freezes before i can connect to the interent. Is there any way i connect to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any software from Earthlink. Just plug your network cable from your computer to the cable modem. If that doesn't work unplug cable modem power cord , shut down your computer, plug in the modem, and restart your computer.

Comment: When you restart - just open "Internet Explorer" - assuming you're using a Windows Machine.